# AuraEnabled returning success records instead of failed records

Tags: lightning, aura, database.insert

I have apex AuraEnabled function which is inserting records for a junction object,
however due to some validation rules, some of the records may get failed.

So I have a solution to maintain a list of failed records as below:-

```
try{
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>(accIds);
        List<String> lstFailedRecords = new List<String>();
        for(Id id:accIds){
            accountIds.add(id);
        }
        for(AGC_AgrScope__c scopeAgr: [SELECT Id, Account__c, Agreement__c 
                                       FROM AGC_AgrScope__c 
                                       WHERE Agreement__c = :agreementId
                                       AND Account__c IN : accIds]) {
                                           accountIds.remove(scopeAgr.Account__c);
                                       }
        List<AGC_AgrScope__c> agrScopeList = new List<AGC_AgrScope__c>();

        for(Id accId:accountIds){
            AGC_AgrScope__c agrScope = new AGC_AgrScope__c();
            agrScope.Account__c = accId;
            agrScope.Agreement__c = agreementId;
            agrScopeList.add(agrScope);
        }
        //Database.insert(agrScopeList);
        insert agrScopeList;
        Database.SaveResult[] sr = Database.insert(agrScopeList,false) ;
        for(Integer i=0;i<sr.size();i++){
           if(!sr[i].isSuccess()){
                lstFailedRecords.add(agrScopeList[i].Account__C);
                system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'MVK Failure --->'+agrScopeList[i]); 
            }
        }
        lstFailedRecords.add('MVK Dummy Value');
        return lstFailedRecords;
```

Note: MVK Dummy Value is just for identifying if the list is getting populated.
Now I am debugging the same on the helper as below:-

```
var action= component.get("c.createAgrScope");
    var recordId = component.get("v.pageReference").state.recordId;
    action.setParams({"accIds": accId,
                      "agreementId": recordId});
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        console.log('MVK Status of Action--->'+a.getState());
        if(a.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
            console.log('MVK Log--->'+a.getReturnValue());
            this.updateCentralPurchasing(component,event);
        }else{
            var errorMsg = a.getError();
            var message = errorMsg[0].message;
            component.set("v.useSpinner", false);
            //alert(message);
            this.handleErrors(errorMsg);
        } 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Now I am trying to insert a record which successfully gets inserted (no validation exceptions), and I am expecting the list to be empty.

However, in the return value I am still getting the id of the successful record, how is it possible? can anyone help with the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to insert the records twice. The first insert happens successfully, while the second one fails (but doesn't throw an exception because allOrNone=false). You'll want to remove `insert agrScopeList;` from your code.

Comment: Thanks fox. I totally missed to comment that. Such a silly thing :)